# One big transfer function or separated over multiple functions

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

Is it better to just keep all the logic within the transfer function or separate it out over 3 functions like I did? Thanks in advance!

```
function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {

    require(_to != address(0));
    if (updateBalance(_to, _value)) { 
        if(allowedContracts[_to]) {
            BIHReceiver receiver = BIHReceiver(_to);
            receiver.tokenFallback(msg.sender,_value);
        }
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, (_value.sub(feePaid)));
        Transfer(msg.sender, feeWallet, (feePaid));
    }
    return true;
}


function updateBalance(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {

    require(_to != address(0));
    if (checkBalance(_to,_value)) {
        uint256 feePaid = (_value.mul(fee).div(10000);
        balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value.sub(feePaid));
        balances[feeWallet] = balances[feeWallet].add(feePaid);
        return true;
    }
} 

function checkBalance(address _to, uint256 _value) public returns (bool) {

    require(_to != address(0));
    if(_value > 0) {
        if(balances[msg.sender] == 0) {
            addresses[indexes[msg.sender]] = addresses[lastIndex];
            indexes[addresses[lastIndex]] = indexes[msg.sender];
            indexes[msg.sender] = 0;
            delete addresses[lastIndex];
            lastIndex--;
        }
        if(indexes[_to]==0) {
            lastIndex++;
            addresses[lastIndex] = _to;
            indexes[_to] = lastIndex;
        }
        return false;
    } else {
        return true; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, developers typically make functions short and simple with limited responsibility for reasons including (but not limited to):

1. it increases readability which makes it easier to follow the intent
2. it's easier to test functions with fewer side effects
3. it's easier to [stay DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and prevent potentially catastrophic mistakes stemming from small differences in what should be the same code

I would say spread it over several functions.